# Howto FilterHashtable with multi condition

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

Need help to filter eventID and processName to get windows event via powershell.

I'm using "get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4688 ; 'ParentProcessName'='*OAW*' ", It doen't work.

I need ID=4688 and ProcessName='*OAW*'

ProcessName is some application like "c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\abcOAWxxx.exe"

Thanks.

Comment: `'OAW'` or `'OWA'`?

Comment: some application name like  c:\xxx\xxx\OWAxxxx.exe

Comment: Are you saying you want to search the log for events where the 'ParentProcessName' is something like '`*OWA*`' (i.e. a partial string match)?  If so, then you're not going to be able to do it with the filter option since `Get-WinEvent` uses a subset of XPath 1.0 behind the scenes and this has some [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events#xpath-10-limitations).  In particular it doesn't support XPath functions like `contains()` that you might use to match like this.